# Oracle - connection Pooling with spring framework

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, oracle10g, ibatis

We are trying to implement Oracle connection pooling with the help of Spring Framework. We are using DBCP connection pooling method. However the integration between DBCP and spring doesn't go down that well.

Problem that we face is that DBCP returns PoolableConnections Object while Oracle expects OracleConnection Objects. (Throws ClassCastException)

It seems that this problem has been handled in Oracle 11g. However I am curious as to how others have implemented Oracle connection pooling using spring framework for Oracle 10g (Using TOMCAT).

We use Ibatis as ORM framework.

I am sure there is a way. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would use Oracles supplied solution, which in included in their ojdbc jars.  The older way was with the class **OracleConnectionPoolDataSource** but now you can set a parameter on a regular **OracleDataSource** and get connection pooling.

Here is how to do it in Spring:

```
<bean id="datasource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" destroy-method="close">
   <property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true" />
   <property name="URL" value="${jdbc.url}" />
   ...all your connection properties
   <property name="connectionCacheProperties">
      <props merge="default">
         <prop key="MinLimit>3</prop>
         <prop key="MaxLimit">20</prop>
      </props>
   </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: there is a typo in there; <proerty name="URL" value="${jdbc.url}" /> should read <property name="URL" value="${jdbc.url}" />

Comment: Nowadays that destroy-method close is deprecated and use of Oracle UCP is recommended: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427890/oracledatasource-vs-oracle-ucp-pooldatasource
Funny enough, it uses OracleDataSource internally via factory and no close is mentioned there at all... Don't know what would happen if that destroy-method is simply omitted here.

Answer (score 4):

I use C3PO to establish the connection. It has also the advantage to do connection pooling for you. Just define a *datasource* bean of type e.g. com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource (or similar) through your spring config files. Before I run into troubles with connection pooling, I even used one of spring (DriverManagerDataSource) that is not advised for production use, because it is not actually doing the connection pooling.

Here is an example spring configuration.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"/>
    <property name="user" value="username"/>
    <property name="password" value="secret"/>
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="5"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20"/>
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="1"/>
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="100"/>
    <property name="maxStatements" value="0"/>
    <property name="checkoutTimeout" value="60000"/>
```

Spring then injects the dataSource bean into Hibernate and all is well. You will also need to have the c3pO jar file on your classpath...

Comment: can you please provide some link for more details on this. A simple example for configuration would be a great pointer.

Comment: I see you are using Oracle xpress edition? Have you tried with a thin client without express edition? any pointers?

Comment: Why use c3p0 when Oracle comes with connection pooling capabilities?

Answer (score 3):

You should *not* implementing your own pooling, if that's what you're using. Tomcat already does that for you, instead, define a data source in Tomcat, and have your ORM framework use it (when you define your Tomcat data source, you can specify the pool configurations there).

If you could post some code snippets, specifically, the relevant Spring context configurations, I can help provide you with how you'd do this.

Here's Tomcat documentation that shows you exactly how you do that:

- http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html

Incidentally, Tomcat uses DBCP also, and it's better to rely on JNDI, as it makes your code more portable (from one environment to another - e.g., dev to staging to production, or even across application servers - e.g., to WebSphere, WebLogic etc).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Using SimpleNativeJdbcExtractor use CommonsDbcpNativeJdbcExtractor to get the native connection. it works.

When working with a simple connection pool that wraps Connections but not Statements, a SimpleNativeJdbcExtractor is often sufficient. However, some pools (like Jakarta's Commons DBCP) wrap all JDBC objects that they return: Therefore, you need to use a specific NativeJdbcExtractor (like CommonsDbcpNativeJdbcExtractor) with them.

Click here [http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/nativejdbc/NativeJdbcExtractor.html]

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking. Please try re-writing this question.

Comment: *I think you mean this answer

Answer (score -1):

I was also facing the same problem as you are.. so i used Oracle Native connection pool.. it works smoothly..

here is the link for the details 
http://www.lambdaprobe.org/d/oracle.shtml

Thanks!
Pratik

Comment: That link was so informative that I cried. Please consider removing this answer

Comment: ...and the domain has since expired.