# JDBC Connection pooling

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, jdbc, connection-pooling

Currently Im looking for a library which provide connection pooling for JDBC. My application is a real-time one. So the connection pooling should support high concurrency. And I also want it to support for both MySQL and Oracle. I looked in to Apache DBCP,and Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool. But it seems they wont suit for my requirement. Is there any other options available?

Comment: http://vigilbose.blogspot.com/2009/03/apache-commons-dbcp-and-tomcat-jdbc.html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520585/connection-pooling-options-with-jdbc-dbcp-vs-c3p0

Comment: Please tell us which aspects of Apache DBCP and Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool make them unsuitable for your needs.

Comment: Also, a jdbc connection pool is never specific to any database. They are in general for any database as long as its JBDC driver is available.

Comment: Here is list of available connection pool libs http://java-source.net/open-source/connection-pools

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the Oracle Universal Connection Pool.  It was reviewed here though: [How good is Oracle Universal Connection Pool (UCP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423490/how-good-is-oracle-universal-connection-pool-ucp).

I've used it before connecting to both Oracle and MySQL instances on large server farms in a large scale multithreaded application and it performed okay, no different that with Apache DBCP.