# Best connection pooling mechanism for non web application?

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g, connection-pooling, spring-jdbc

My application has been using OracleConnectionPooling for a while but after seeing some sluggish database performance I decieded to use the new UCP (Universal Connection Pool) by oracle as it provides statement caching. In my research online, I found out many stack overflow users recommend against UCP. I am using UCP version 11.2.0.4. I have noticed very minor improvements by using UCP with statement caching of upto 200 statements per connection and switching most of the application to prepared statements.

I have seen questions on stackoverflow like one below that make me doubt my decision to use UCP.

[How good is Oracle Universal Connection Pool (UCP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423490/how-good-is-oracle-universal-connection-pool-ucp)

I do want more performance improvement in my application. So what connection pooling mechanism is the best choice UCP, Tomact or some other pooing mechanism ?

Also, I heard using spring jdbc template with connection pooling is better choice since it takes care of closing connections, statments and result sets. what are your thoughts ?

Comment: The connection pool is very rarely where performance problems lie. They lie in the database queries themselves, the lack of index, etc. Don't try to optimize if you don't know precisely what is causing your performance problems.

Comment: Performance problems in my application is mostly due to too many sql interactions. batching requests in not an option so I am trying to optimize the way statements are handled. Using UCP statement caching with prepared statements seemed like a good approach but I am in doubt after reading responess that don't recommed it. Since most responses recommending against ucp are more than a year old so I wanted to get a fresh view on this topic.