# Oracle PoolDataSource leaves DB cursor open until commit(), is this expected behavior?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Unless I call `Connection.commit()`, the DB cursor remains open after a query. I believe this behavior is causing my application to leak cursors and experience DB errors related to cursor usage.

It seems like the `commit()` call should be unnecessary... Is this behavior expected? Is there any way to configure the JDBC connection pool to reliably release cursors when resources are closed, without calling commit?

I am using this query to find open cursors:

`select * from v$open_cursor where CURSOR_TYPE = 'OPEN'`

If I call `commit()` after closing the `statement` and `ResultSet`, no cursors are open during the `sleep()`

```
   try (Connection con = pooledDataSource.getConnection()) {
        try (PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("select 1 from dual a");
             ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery()) {
        }
        con.commit();
    }

    Thread.sleep(20000);
```

If I call commit prior to closing `statement` and `ResultSet`, I find the sql `select 1 from b` when I query for open cursors during the sleep().

```
        try (Connection con = pooledDataSource.getConnection();
             PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("select 1 from dual b");
             ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery()) {{

             con.commit();
        }}

        Thread.sleep(20000);
```

Same thing here. If I don't call `commit()` I find `select 1 from dual c in my open cursor query, which remains open until the JVM exits.

```
        try (Connection con = pooledDataSource.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("select 1 from dual c");
                ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery()) {{
        }}
```

These are my configurations

```
        PoolDataSource pooledDataSource = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();
        pooledDataSource.setConnectionFactoryClassName("oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource");
        pooledDataSource.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//" + host + ":1521/" + service);
        pooledDataSource.setUser(user);
        pooledDataSource.setPassword(pw);
        pooledDataSource.setInitialPoolSize(1);
        pooledDataSource.setMinPoolSize(1);
        pooledDataSource.setMaxPoolSize(1);
        pooledDataSource.setAbandonedConnectionTimeout(5);
        pooledDataSource.setConnectionWaitTimeout(5);
        pooledDataSource.setInactiveConnectionTimeout(5);
```

Comment: What version driver and UCP are you using?

Comment: @KrisRice I observed the same behavior with `11.2.0.1.0` and `12.1.0.2`. I'm using `oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior doesn't reproduce in 12.2.0.1 ([JDBC Download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-ucp-122-3110062.html)) using the following test [UCPTest.java](https://gist.github.com/lavarene/898b056ce83cfa31f4e05582dc575930). In any case please note that this isn't a bug. What you observe is due to the fact that the driver doesn't make a roundtrip when a statement is closed. Instead the operation is piggybacked on the next roundtrip. This is an optimization to reduce the overall number of roundtrips between the client and the server. The reason why you don't observe the same behavior in 12.2.0.1 is because UCP makes a one-way trip to the database when the connection is released to the pool and that flushes the piggyback calls. If you want to artificially flush the piggyback calls you can also do 
`((oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection)con).pingDatabase()` which is a full roundtrip and hence carries along the queue of piggyback calls.

Comment: thanks, this is working for me with 12.2.0.1... How can I investigate patching the 11.2.0.1.0 jar to fix this behavior?

Comment: You would have to follow up with Oracle Support for that. Do you need a patch for 11.2?

Comment: Yes, if we could patch 11.2 to fix this issue, that would be very useful for me

Comment: After further investigations, this isn't a bug. It's just that the network message to close a cursor is piggybacked on the next roundtrip and so closing a statement doesn't actually close the cursor immediately. I'm changing my reply accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for following up on this, I understand it may not be a bug, but I'm fairly sure it is responsible for my application leaking cursors... Am I correct in thinking that if a session makes only 1 query, it's cursor will never be closed? For instance, there is some page ping.jsp, and some malicious user curls ping.jsp from 500 different proxies, I will end up with 500 leaked cursors? I believe this is the behavior I'm observing, does it seem reasonable that 11.2 would produce this behavior?

Comment: If a session makes only 1 query then the cursor will be closed the next time the connection is used, that is, the next time the connection is borrowed from the connection cache. Assuming that your connection cache is active, connection are constantly being used and the queue of piggybacked calls is flushed rapidly.

Comment: I found a cursor that stays open after I call both `pingDatabase()` and `commit()` on its connection, any suggestions what else I could try? (driver upgrade is not a good short term option)

Comment: Are you using statement caching? That would leave the cursor opened. Have you tracked the cursor to its creator? Is it your Java app? Or a PLSQL proc?