# what's causing OracleUcpConnectionManager.getConnection("some_resource_name") to fail?

Tags: oracle, spring, configuration, junit

I have some code that's calling `OracleUcpConnectionManager.getConnection("some_resource_name")` in a test that's failing with an `SQLException` that says: `Invalid Universal Connection Pool configuration`.  I've checked and this same code is being called in production, and it works.  The resource name (string being passed to `.getConnection` is the same for both the test and production code.  I'm assuming it has to be some configuration that automagically happens through spring, so I sorted through the XML files in `WEB-INF` and tried adding this to the test:

```
//manually scan the application context (this is done with XML configuration in the normal application)
//thanks: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RC1/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-java-instantiating-container-scan
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
context.scan("some.package.here");
context.refresh();
```

Based on this in my dispacther-servlet.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="some.package.here" />
```

*Note: the `context:` prefix here is defined as `xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"`*

That didn't have any (noticeable) effect.

I've also been sifting through oracle's site for a few days and haven't found much related to that error (the error code is `UCP-45006` by the way ([see: *error codes on oracle's site*](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24693_01/java.11203/e12265/err_cod_ref.htm)), and a search for that didn't turn up much for me)

I also thought this question might be handy: [OracleDataSource vs. Oracle UCP PoolDataSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427890/oracledatasource-vs-oracle-ucp-pooldatasource), however I don't have any of that configuration in my `.xml` or `.properties` files currently (this is a preexisting project), and (as already noted) `.getConnection(String)` works fine when running the code in production, but not when running as a JUnit test.

Is there something I should be looking for in the logs?  I'm unsure what to try next.

**Update**: it's failing at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.setConnectionFactoryClassName (which is causing the SQLExcpetion) AND (bonus here), I found [the javadocs for that](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16338_01/java.112/e12826/oracle/ucp/jdbc/PoolDataSourceImpl.html#setConnectionFactoryClassName_java_lang_String_).

**Update Update**: Our properties file, which has the value needed by 'setConnectionFactoryClassName' appears to be loaded in the regular project, but not when testing.  After searching around a bit, it seems to be loaded automagically, after we pass the JVM this argument: `-DapplicationProperties="C:\full\path\to\our\file.properties"`.  Now to figure out if spring handles that or java does...

**Update Update Update**: I can verify the location of the properties file is being passed to the test, ([thanks to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490869/how-to-get-vm-arguments-from-inside-of-java-application))