# Difference between OracleDataSource , Oracle UCP, Commons DBCP and Tomcat Connection Pool?

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, connection-pooling

I read a few links on stackoverflow, mkyong and offical docs of Tomcat JDBC Pool. And I am too confused.

Points to be Noted:

1) I understand Oracle Universal Connection Pooling  is a new concept and is unstable. In this link the person asks about **OracleDataSource**(please note it) [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427890/oracledatasource-vs-oracle-ucp-pooldatasource)

2) So Lets say UCP is totally different. 
Now Mkyong(RESPECT) has this tutorial available. [Link2](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-configure-mysql-datasource-in-tomcat-6/)

3) And then there is this Link on Tomcat's offical Docs [Link3](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html)

What is or is there a difference between **OracleDataSource** and **Commons DBCP** ? Is it something like we configure OracleDataSource using Commons DBCP

What method of Datasource Pool Configuration is MKYONG Using?

And what is Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool? [Link4](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Introduction)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read some more up to date documentation.

UCP is neither new nor unstable.

The OracleDataSource is how you connect to the Oracle database from Java.

Commons DBCP is a database connection pool.

Yes, you would/could  use Commons DBCP to pool connections from an OracleDataSource.

MKYOUNG is using Commons DBCP. Tomcat automatically uses Commons DBCP for all DataSources.

Tomcat JDBC is an alternative to connection pool. It has significant advantages in multi-threaded environments compared to Commons DBCP 1.x. When compared to Commons DBCP 2.x the differences are much smaller. Between the two I'd recommend Commons DBCP 2.x by default - it appears to be more actively maintained.

Comment: DBCP 2.x Requires Java 7. And Tomcat JDBC Pool is available from Tomcat 7.0.19 version onwards and Requires Java 6 minimum.
I read more documentation and understood exactly what you said.

Comment: A Link that helped me clear my confusion. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711943/tomcat-dbcp-vs-commons-dbcp
See answer given by "Florent Guillaume" and "Pavel" .

Answer (score 0):

UCP(Universal Connection Pool) has been around since 11.1.0.7.  UCP along with RAC, RAC One and ADG is a tested and certified combination for handling database failovers. For more details on UCP, refer to [UCP Developer's guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJUCP/toc.htm).