# Oracle Data source configuration in MULE(AnyPoint Studio)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, mule, datasource, mule-studio

I use this config for oracle database in Mule:

```
    <spring:beans>               
    <spring:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" destroy-method="shutdown" name="Bean">
        <spring:property name="driverName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
        <spring:property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.28.129:1521:orcl"/>
        <spring:property name="user" value="username" />
        <spring:property name="password" value="123456" />
    </spring:bean>
</spring:beans>


<db:oracle-config name="Oracle_Configuration" useXaTransactions="true" dataSource-ref="dataSource"   doc:name="Oracle Configuration">

    <db:pooling-profile maxPoolSize="10" minPoolSize="5" acquireIncrement="2"/>
</db:oracle-config>
```

***I added ojdbc14.jar as a external jar file into my project**
but when I test connection in Global Elements in Anypoint Studio I see this error:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**how can I solve this issue?**

Also I have to say that in a main method I checked the connection and it was ok, this is Main method structure:

```
    import java.sql.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

           try {
                 Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
           } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
           }

            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection
                ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.28.129:1521:orcl", "eslami", "123456");
                                // @machineName:port:SID,   userid,  password

            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("select * from person");
            while (rset.next())
                System.out.println (rset.getString(1) +  "  " + rset.getString(2) + "  " +  
                                    rset.getString(3) +  "  " + rset.getString(4) + "  " + 
                                    rset.getString(5));   // Print row 1
            stmt.close();
      }

}
```

Comment: Please check here for oracle configuration :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398962/setting-up-an-oracle-connection-pool-using-spring-in-mule-ee-3-2-2

Comment: @AnirbanSenChowdhary, Thanks for your reply, Is it possible for you that help me more? that link made me confused? what shall I do exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you can configure your oracle :-

```
<spring:beans> 
<spring:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"    destroy-method="close"> 
        <spring:property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/> 
        <spring:property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.28.129:1521:xe"/> 
        <spring:property name="username" value="yourUserName"/> 
        <spring:property name="password" value="yourPassword"/> 
        <spring:property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/> 
        <spring:property name="initialSize" value="10"/> 
        <spring:property name="maxActive" value="50"/> 
        </spring:bean> 
</spring:beans>

<db:generic-config name="Database_Configuration" dataSource-ref="dataSource" doc:name="Generic Database Configuration" />

 <flow name="mainFlow">
     <http:listener config-ref="httpListenerConfig" path="/*" doc:name="HTTP" allowedMethods="GET"/> 
///////////////////////////////////////

Your Code
////////////////////////////////////
 <db:select config-ref="Database_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
    <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[select * from yourtableName]]></db:parameterized-query>
</db:select>
</flow>
```

You can use the above configuration and change as per your ip, username, password etc

And don't forget to add `commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar` or other version and `ojdbc6.jar` in your classpath

Comment: Thanks for your reply,with your guidance I could connect Mule to oracle

Comment: You just made my day.

Answer (score 0):

One clear difference from your working Java example and the non-working mule code is the XATransactions. Could you try turn them off and see if there is a difference?

Otherwise, supply your version of Anypoint and Mule and I'll give this code a testrun.

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply, I tried your solution and put useXaTransactions="false" but after test connection I couldn't be success. Again I saw error box. I use this version of AnyPoint Studio : Anypoint Studio - Tooling for Mule ESB

Anypoint Studio January 2015 Release
Version: 5.0.0